# help texturing and adding materials to a violin

Tags: texturing, materials

I would like to find a way to make the rune glow and make the violin look somewhat realistic. I have tried using some textures from textures.com, but I could use some tips.

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is another picture when you click on ]2

Comment: you need to unwrap it and put a wood texture on it, with a bit of glossiness